# How to Track Non Skeletal Point Or Extend the Sketetal Tracking Framework to Add Addition Joints

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect.toolbox

Say for example if you wanted to track a tennis ball or extend the Skeletal Tracking Framework. How would you achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about something like this?

"Kinect 3D Projectile Tracker" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUv-LN26SGI

Unfortunately, the github link for the video is 404'd, so you wouldn't be able to look at the code for it.  I suspect they used more general computer vision technique.

You could probably try and 'recognize' a tennis (or other) ball by color on the color stream (ie, what I think is happening in the above video), but that wouldn't really be 'extending' the skeletal tracking framework - I don't think that can be done, unfortunately.

At least not with the first generation kinect (I've not played with the second gen).

"Tennis Ball Tracking Using openCV" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKzQ3-iOK7k

Has a link to a tutorial on how to track a ball by color in your code, if that helps.